Gradle task assembleDebug failed during Flutter debug
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: services.gradle.org
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:572)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl
.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:174)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:533)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:638)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1665)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

When i ran the debug I was thrown with this exception
please help me sort this issue
the build was working fine previously and it aint working anymore

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
